# Não estou conseguindo extrair um dado do json - React-js

Tags: json, react, axios

senhores(as).

não estou conseguindo extrair um dado para enviar para api.
no caminho /cases a api fornece dados json.

```
useEffect(()=>  {
    api.get('cases',{

    }).then(response =>{
        setcases(response.data)
    })
}, [])
```

Ao acessar a rota cases, e renderizar ela fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

cada caso tem uma id que vem do banco de dados (na imagem seria 23 e 24) e preciso mandar esse ID para o back quando eu inscrever-me nele.

Aqui no {caso.id} eu trago o id do caso da tabela mysql porém não estou conseguindo enviar para api esse mesmíssimo dado no método post, e aqui vem o problema, como eu consigo fazer isso? quais as formas para capturar esse valor ID? Estou utilizando o Axios.

```
async function handleInsc(){

    try {

        const config ={
            headers:{Authorization:userid}
        }

         await api.post('cases/inscMyCases',{
            cases_ids:cases.id/  */aqui vai o id*/
         },config)

        alert('Inscrito')

    } catch (error) {
        alert('erro na inscrição')

    }

}
```

abaixo o código completo.

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {Link, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import {FiTrash2,FiPhoneForwarded,FiPower} from 'react-icons/fi'

import  './styleCases.css'

import api from '../../services/api'

export default function Profile(){
    const[cases, setcases] = useState([])   
    const history =useHistory()

    const usuario = localStorage.getItem('userName')
    const userid = localStorage.getItem('userId')
    useEffect(()=>  {
        api.get('cases',{

        }).then(response =>{
            setcases(response.data)

        })
    },[])


    function handleLogout(){
        localStorage.clear()
        history.push('/')
    }

    async function handleInsc(){

        try {

            const config ={
                headers:{Authorization:userid}
            }

             await api.post('cases/inscMyCases',{
                cases_ids:caso.id/*/aqui tem soluçao*/
             },config)

            alert('Inscrito')

        } catch (error) {
            alert('erro na inscrição')

        }

    }

    return(
        <div className="profile-container">
            <header>
                <span>SEJA BEM VINDO(a) {usuario}</span>

                <Link className="button" to="/alerts/newCase">Cadastrar um alerta de trabalho</Link>
                <Link className="button" to="profile">Volte para sua pagina de perfil</Link>


                <button onClick={handleLogout} type="button"></button>
                <FiPower size={18} color="#e02041"></FiPower>

            </header>

            <h1>Casos Cadastrados</h1>

                <ul>{cases.map(caso =>( 
                    <li key={cases.id}>
                    <strong>CASO:{caso.id}</strong>
                    <p>{caso.title}</p>


                    <strong>DESCRIÇÃO:</strong>
                    <p>{caso.description}</p>

                    <strong>VALOR:</strong>
                    <p>{Intl.NumberFormat('pt-br',{style:'currency',currency:'BRL'}).format(caso.value)}</p>
                    <p><button onClick={handleInsc} className="FaWhatsapp" to="profile/inscMyCases" >Candidatar-se</button></p>                                      


                    </li> 

                ))}                     

                </ul>
        </div>


    )
}
```

Comment: Você está usando o que no back?

Abre o DevTools do navegador pressionando `F12` ou `ctrl + shift + i` e vá na aba `console` para ver tudo o que ocorre de erros. Coloca um `console.log(response)` para ver o que é retornado da endpoint `/cases`.

Comment: estou usando node, o erro que vem do back 'Column 'cases_ids' cannot be null', se dá por que estou não estou enviando nada no cases_ids. porém pra enviar o que eu quero, preciso extrair o ID que esta aqui dentro da <li key={caso.id}>, vou tentar reescrever o post pra tentar ser um pouco mais claro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está enviando `cases_ids: caso.id`, sendo que `caso.id` não existe no escopo da função  e pode enviar esse `id` por parâmetro para função, assim:

```
<button onClick={() => handleInsc(caso.id)}
```

e alterar o método para:

```
async function handleInsc(id) {
```

e na hora de enviar o `ID` para o `back-end`, coloca ele no corpo da requisição assim:

```
cases_ids: id
```

Comment: É isso mesmo.. estava passa somente o retorno da function, sendo o correto a função com o param... valeu meu nobre Lucas Bittencourt